How to combine multiple Copy to Clipboard Functions?
I'm trying to figure out how to copy multiple Copy to Clipboard buttons into a single script.
My page has dynamic text areas that are filled out as the user completes the form and each textarea has its own copy to clipboard button:


function CopyTemplateField1() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("TemplateField1");
  copyText.select();
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
}

function CopyTemplateField2() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("TemplateField2");
  copyText.select();
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
}

function CopyTemplateField3() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("TemplateField3");
  copyText.select();
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
}
<tr>
  <td><textarea id="TemplateField1"></textarea></td>
  <td><img src="copybutton.png" onClick="CopyTemplateField1();"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><textarea id="TemplateField2"></textarea></td>
  <td><img src="copybutton.png" onClick="CopyTemplateField2();"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><textarea id="TemplateField3"></textarea></td>
  <td><img src="copybutton.png" onClick="CopyTemplateField3();"></td>
</tr>



I still want each copy button to copy the text from the associated textarea but have the three separate functions combined into one function that will differentiate between which button is pressed and copy that text to the clipboard.
I tried using if/else but kept giving errors.  Searched for similar articles but couldn't find anything that matched.  If there is another method to use but prefer to stay with JavaScript as the page is pretty simplistic.

Instead of getting the textarea by the id, select it from the markup structure. Something like txtarea = e.target.closest('tr').firstElementChild.firstElementChild;. You need to pass event object to the event handlers. And, rather use addEventListener to attach the events, see also event delegation to simplify your code.

Use function parameters: onClick="copyValue('TemplateField2');"

Why did you use Function with uppercase F? I'm surprised it works on your side. I had to edit it to  function to make the snippet work.

Please note that navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value) is blocked on stackoverflow so the snippet won't work like this. Instead you could find the textarea element and try textarea.select(); document.execCommand('copy'); to reproduce it here. navigator.clipboard.writeText() requires a safer context than the snippets on Stackoverflow and is a modern and better approach.

Using function parameters seems to be the best option
<tr>
  <td><textarea id="TemplateField1"></textarea></td>
  <td><img src="copybutton.png" onClick="CopyTemplateField(1);"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><textarea id="TemplateField2"></textarea></td>
  <td><img src="copybutton.png" onClick="CopyTemplateField(2);"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><textarea id="TemplateField3"></textarea></td>
  <td><img src="copybutton.png" onClick="CopyTemplateField(3);"></td>
</tr>

function CopyTemplateField(n) {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("TemplateField" + n);
  copyText.select();
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
}

